# Lighthouse Nested Mutations FK Field not being filled

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm having some issues wrapping my head around nested mutations with Lighthouse.

I've got two models that are related: `Ams\Account` hasMany `Ams\Contact`. This is the `Ams\Contact` model:

```php
namespace App\Models\Ams;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Contact extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'ams_contacts';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
        'ams_account_id',
        'forename',
        'surname',
        'active',
        'email'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'forename' => 'string',
        'surname' => 'string',
        'active' => 'boolean',
        'email' => 'string'
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        'ams_account_id' => 'required',
        'forename' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ];

    public function amsAccount(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Ams\Account::class, 'ams_account_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

My GraphQL schema file looks like this:

```
"A datetime string with format `Y-m-d H:i:s`, e.g. `2018-01-01 13:00:00`."
scalar DateTime @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\DateTime")

"A date string with format `Y-m-d`, e.g. `2011-05-23`."
scalar Date @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\Date")

type Query {
    amsAccounts: [AmsAccount!]! @paginate(defaultCount: 10 model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Account")
    amsAccount(id: ID @globalId): AmsAccount @find(model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Account")

    amsContacts: [AmsContact!]! @paginate(defaultCount: 10 model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Contact")
    amsContact(id: ID @globalId): AmsContact @find(model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Contact")
}

type Mutation {
    createAmsAccount(
        input: CreateAmsAccountInput! @spread
    ): AmsAccount @create(model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Account")

    updateAmsAccount(
        input: UpdateAmsAccountInput! @spread
    ): AmsAccount @update(model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Account")

    deleteAmsAccount(
        id: ID! @rules(apply: ["required"])
    ): AmsAccount @delete(model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Account")

    createAmsContact(
        input: CreateAmsContactInput! @spread
    ): AmsContact @create(model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Contact")

    updateAmsContact(
        input: UpdateAmsContactInput! @spread
    ): AmsContact @update(model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Contact")

    deleteAmsContact(
        id: ID! @rules(apply: ["required"])
    ): AmsContact @delete(model: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Contact")
}

type AmsAccount @node(namespace: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Account") {
    id: ID! @globalId
    name: String!
    url: String
    telephone: String!
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
}

input CreateAmsAccountInput {
    name: String!
    url: String
    telephone: String!
}

input UpdateAmsAccountInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    url: String
    telephone: String!
}

input UpsertAmsAccountInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    url: String
    telephone: String!
}

type AmsContact @node(namespace: "App\\Models\\Ams\\Contact") {
    id: ID! @globalId
    forename: String!
    surname: String!
    active: Boolean
    email: String!
    amsAccount: AmsAccount! @belongsTo
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
}

input CreateAmsContactInput {
    forename: String!
    surname: String!
    active: Boolean
    email: String!
    amsAccount: CreateAmsAccountBelongsTo
}

input UpdateAmsContactInput {
    id: ID!
    forename: String!
    surname: String!
    active: Boolean
    email: String!
    amsAccount: UpdateAmsAccountBelongsTo
}

input UpsertAmsContactInput {
    id: ID!
    forename: String!
    surname: String!
    active: Boolean
    email: String!
    amsAccount: UpsertAmsAccountBelongsTo
}

input CreateAmsAccountBelongsTo {
    connect: ID
    create: CreateAmsAccountInput
    update: UpdateAmsAccountInput
    upsert: UpsertAmsAccountInput
}

input UpdateAmsAccountBelongsTo {
    connect: ID
    create: CreateAmsAccountInput
    update: UpdateAmsAccountInput
    upsert: UpsertAmsAccountInput
    disconnect: Boolean
    delete: Boolean
}

input UpsertAmsAccountBelongsTo {
    connect: ID
    create: CreateAmsAccountInput
    update: UpdateAmsAccountInput
    upsert: UpsertAmsAccountInput
    disconnect: Boolean
    delete: Boolean
}
```

When I try and run the following mutation in the playground:

```
mutation {
  createAmsContact(
    input: {
      forename: "Jane"
      surname: "Doe"
      active: true
      email: "jd@example.com"
      amsAccount: {
        connect: 1
      }
    }
  ) {
    id
    forename
    surname
    amsAccount: id
  }
}
```

I get an error about the following error message:

```
"debugMessage": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'ams_account_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `ams_contacts` (`forename`, `surname`, `active`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Jane, Doe, 1, jd@example.com, 2020-04-12 15:31:52, 2020-04-12 15:31:52))"
```

I've tried a number of fixes and suggestions from around the web, and as far as I can see my schema follows the defined format from the documentation, but I cannot fathom out why it's not working.

I've also confirmed that the simple mutation for the account work fine. I also get a similar error message when I try to create a new account at the same time as the contact.

My inclination is that it's to do with the namespaces of the different models, but I can't imagine I'm the first to have this requirement, nor can I find any references to how to overcome this.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So I wasn't actually a million miles from the mark with my Namespace problem.

The problem lies with the Model file, specifically here:

```php
public function amsAccount(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Ams\Account::class, 'ams_account_id', 'id');
    }
```

The issue is that the `BelongsTo` had not been specified in the `use` clauses at the start of the model class. As such the return class type could not be detected properly.

As such it was necessary to add the following to the `use` clauses at the top of the file:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
```

This applies to other relationship types.

This is what the [Documentation](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#return-types-required) states, but is so subtle that it didn't click.

RTFM.

Thanks for all who looked and hope this helps someone else in the future.